# Converting numbers to hexadecimal

Tags: converters, type-conversion

What is the fastest and easiest way to convert number  such as

```
 short int x = -0x6858
```

into hexa?

it would be easy if it was easy number such as`-0xABC` in this case it would be `FFFFF544` but i fail to find a way how to convert "more difficult numbers"

Comment: How did you convert `-0xABC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be like this for printing purposes:
`printf("%08x\n", x);`

You can of course use `sprintf` to convert the variable.

Comment: the short int x was just for bytes , i  would like to know how to convert it manually = without using C or any else tool

Comment: You mean, as in decimal subtraction? Take FFFFF.. (# of Fs according to the size) and do the math. Same logic as in decimal - carry keeping, etc...